# Как получить ссылку на поддомен?

Tags: php

Имеется ссылка на поддомене sp.site.ru:

```
<a id="add_bbs" class="btn" href="/arenda">Найти</a>
```

в результате в ссылку попадает адрес основного сайта, не поддомена:

```
site.ru/arenda
```

Как это исправить, чтобы была ссылка такого вида `sp.site.ru/arenda`, т.е. чтобы не указывать адрес статически?

P.S.
добавлю, что в корне сайта такие папки:

...
/public_html
----/тут основной сайт
...
/sp
----/public_html
--------/тут папки и файлы поддомена

Comment: Может [<base>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/base) поможет вам. Укажите там путь с поддоменом.

Comment: @word, тут скорее всего в настройках веб-сервера проблемы

Comment: и убедитесь, что вас поддомен на самом деле не перенаправляет на основной сайт

Comment: @teran, на поддомене нет перенаправления на основной сайт, т.к. данная ссылка рабочая `sp.site.ru`, т.е. главная страница поддомена

Comment: @teran, обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: если просто `sp.site.ru/arenda` вбить в адресную строку, то что происходит, тоже главный открывается, или остается на поддомене?

Comment: @teran, кстати да, `sp.site.ru` эта ссылка работает, а вот `sp.site.ru/arenda` эта перебрасывает на главный сайт `site.ru/arenda`

Comment: вот про это и речь. Октройте инструменты по ф12- сеть. вбейте ссылку и посмотрите какие запросы-ответы. Вероятно вам прийдет сначала `301`й редирект на основной сайт. А потом уже `200 ОК`, но от основного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег `<a href="...">` в качестве значений может принимать только правильно сформированные URL-адреса. Такие адреса могут быть всего четырёх видов:

1. `http://yourdomain.com/dir/subdir/example.html` — полный URL с указанием всех параметров доступа к ресурсу;
2. `//yourdomain.com/dir/subdir/example.html` — сокращённый URL без указания протокола доступа. В этом случае браузер использует тот же протокол, что и у текущего документа;
3. `/dir/subdir/example.html` — относительный URL, с указанием полного пути от корня текущего сайта. Протокол доступа и сайт браузер использует те же, что и у текущего документа;
4. `subdir/example.html` — относительный URL, с указанием пути, относительно расположения текущего документа. Протокол доступа и сайт браузер использует те же, что и у текущего документа;

Никакие иные варианты невозможны. Так что, увы, но вам либо придётся явно указывать адрес поддомена (ибо для браузера это другой сервер — он не отличает поддомены от просто других доменов), либо переносить ресурс внутрь текущего сайта.